# How to fix "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException"

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to fix error as follows:

"**android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**"

here are my code.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    onShowMessage();
}

public void removeContent() {
    LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_list);
    list.removeAllViews();
}

public void onShowMessage() {
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String id = "id1";
            String message = "message1";
            String response = HTTPUtils.HTTPPost(Global.MESSAGE_URL, 
                    "id", id, 
                    "message", message);
            process(response);
        }
    });
    myThread.start();
}

private void process(String response) {
    if (response == null || response.equals("")) {
        return;
    } else {
        try {
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = FbUtil.parseJson(response);
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                showErrorMessage();
            }
            if (json.has("exception")) {
                showErrorMessage();
                return;
            } else {
                Global.list = JsonParser.getInfo(json);
                removeContent();
                initView();
                return;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
        return;
    }
}
```

}

error occur on removeContent();

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating Views in a different thread

`removeContent();
 initView();`

Call this two methods in a UI thread like.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            removeContent();
            initView();             
        }
    });
```